# Android Image Processing using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, bitmap, face-recognition

I am processing a camera frame using OpenCV. The functionality is working fine. However, it takes between **40~60 ms** to process each frame. I am wondering if there is a possibility to improve the execution time. Following are the steps I take before I pass the mat to OpenCV cascade classifier.

```
mPixelBuf.rewind();
GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mPixelBuf);

Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mPixelBuf.rewind();
bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(mPixelBuf);

// received inverted(upside-down) bitmap. Fixing it.
android.graphics.Matrix m = new android.graphics.Matrix();
m.preScale(1, -1);

Bitmap flipped = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, m, false);

Mat mat = new Mat();
// convert bitmap to mat
Utils.bitmapToMat(flipped, mat);
// apply gray scale
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

// pass the mat to cascade classifier...
```

I guess there could be some smart ways to avoid this extra processing or perhaps reduce the image resolution for faster image processing.